# Passing java options to jetty.sh

Tags: jetty

Normally, I'll start jetty (version 8) using this:

```
 java -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC start.jar
```

But now I'm using jetty.sh to run jetty on startup.
Does anyone know how can I pass the above java options to jetty?  Is it through the jetty.xml file? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On line 43 of jetty.sh you will see.

```
# JAVA_OPTIONS
#   Extra options to pass to the JVM
```

Just put this after it:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use {JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS [options]"}
Or does it not matter because they are options and don't overwrite exiting args?