# Jetty - How to Configure JAVA_OPTIONS in linux

Tags: java, linux, jetty

I have jetty status like this

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/jetty/bin# ./jetty.sh status
Checking arguments to Jetty:
START_INI      =  /opt/jetty/start.ini
JETTY_HOME     =  /opt/jetty
JETTY_BASE     =  /opt/jetty
JETTY_CONF     =  /opt/jetty/etc/jetty.conf
JETTY_PID      =  /var/run/jetty.pid
JETTY_START    =  /opt/jetty/start.jar
JETTY_LOGS     =  /opt/jetty/logs
JETTY_STATE    =  /opt/jetty/jetty.state
CLASSPATH      =
JAVA           =  /usr/bin/java
JAVA_OPTIONS   =  -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -server -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Djetty.logs=/opt/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
JETTY_ARGS     =  jetty.state=/opt/jetty/jetty.state jetty-logging.xml jetty-started.xml
RUN_CMD        =  /usr/bin/java -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -server -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Djetty.logs=/opt/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar jetty.state=/opt/jetty/jetty.state jetty-logging.xml jetty-started.xml
```

I want to add in JAVA_OPTION **-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit**

How to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/default/jetty` file to specify the `JAVA_OPTIONS` you want to use.

Comment: I want to ask, i have server with 16gb ram memory and 4cpu. Can you provide the best jvm configuration in JAVA_OPTIONS?

Answer (score 0):

pass the option when starting jetty, as discussed here -
[Passing java options to jetty.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647795/passing-java-options-to-jetty-sh)

Or, if you want to change in the configuration file, check here -
https://help.percussion.com/rhythmyx/implementation/jetty/memory-and-java-settings-for-jetty.html

basically copy the config file from -

```
/opt/jetty/defaults/start.d/jvm.ini
```

to -

```
/opt/jetty/base/start.d/jvm.ini
```

and add the desired option there.

Comment: This will fork the JVM to accomplish the result you are looking for, resulting in 2 JVMs (the start.jar one and the forked one to satisfy the jvm.ini requirements).  Since his existing `JAVA_OPTIONS` has `-Xms4096m` this is basically wasting 4GB of memory on the start.jar JVM for no good reason.